# Trouble installing System.FilePath.Find

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to install [System.FilePath.Find](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/FileManip/0.3.2/doc/html/System-FilePath-Find.html) module. I tried using

```
cabal install FileManip
```

but it failed:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring FileManip-0.3.3.1...
Preprocessing library FileManip-0.3.3.1...
Building FileManip-0.3.3.1...
[1 of 5] Compiling System.FilePath.Error ( System/FilePath/Error.hs, dist/build/System/FilePath/Error.o )
[2 of 5] Compiling System.FilePath.Manip ( System/FilePath/Manip.hs, dist/build/System/FilePath/Manip.o )
[3 of 5] Compiling System.FilePath.GlobPattern ( System/FilePath/GlobPattern.hs, dist/build/System/FilePath/GlobPattern.o )
[4 of 5] Compiling System.FilePath.Glob ( System/FilePath/Glob.hs, dist/build/System/FilePath/Glob.o )
[5 of 5] Compiling System.FilePath.Find ( System/FilePath/Find.hs, dist/build/System/FilePath/Find.o )

System/FilePath/Find.hs:174:20:
    Not in scope: data constructor `State'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
FileManip-0.3.3.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$  ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
$  cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.8.0
using version 1.8.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: To explain the error: `FileManip` expects `mtl-1.*`, where `State` was a separate monad with equally named type and data constructor, but has no upper bound on the `mtl` dependence. `cabal` tried to install it using `mtl-2.*`, where `State s` is a type synonym for `StateT s Identity`. Regarding the problems upgrading GHC, my advice is to compile it from source and forget about the distribution packages after you got one GHC to bootstrap (installing them in `$HOME` means it's simple to wipe if something breaks, and you still have a working one in the system directories to get started again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FileManip package is marked as obsolete on Hackage and the last version is from 2010.

Use [filemanip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip) (lower case) instead. It should be more up to date.

You might also want to upgrade your GHC. Version 6.12.1 is from December 2009.

Comment: I know that my ghc is a bit old :) I'm still using Linux Mint 10 (== Ubuntu 10.10), so I can't update it without a lot of trouble.